# expected primary expression before . token

Tags: c++

How do I make use of the structure members fast and interactive in C++ with the help of a structure?

```
struct op {
    bool fast;
    bool interactive;
}
format_options = {
    .fast        = false,
    .interactive = true
};
```

Comment: C99 tagged initialization syntax is not part of standard C++.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need this style of object initialization (and you cannot do this in C++ as this is c99 supported) in C++ because you can use a constructor.

```
struct op {
    bool fast;
    bool interactive;
    op () :
       fast(false),
       interactive(true)
    {}
};
```

This will server your purpose

Answer (score 0):

Appart from the missing semicollon after the struct declaration, you must tell the compiler that 'format_options' is of the type 'op'. The correct code would be:

```
struct op {
    bool fast;
    bool interactive;
};

op format_options = {
    .fast        = false,
    .interactive = true
};
```

Comment: No, it's not official C++ yet. Designated initializers are in the latest C++20 draft, but were not in C++17.  g++ allows them by default (since it has the code and logic for them to support C99), but will point out it's invalid if you add -Wpedantic.